# ViewDidLoad Many Views Created

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, viewdidload

Currently in my app when the user enters his or her credentials into the textfield's and clicks sign in, the transition from the `SignInViewController` to the `TableView` on the next `ViewController` is extremely laggy.

**In total in my SignInViewController ViewDidLoad I am programmatically creating:**

- UIScrollView
- Three image views (all positioned in the scrollView as a vertical scroller of the three images)
- 4 buttons
- 2 textFields (password and username)
- Page controller (for the scrollview)

Is this too many views to create in viewDidLoad?

So could this be the reason why when the user clicks the sign in button, the transition from the `SignInViewController` to the next `ViewController` (which has a very simple UITableView on) is laggy?

Comment: I doubt that creating the views is your problem.  How do you create and present the next view controller - show code.  Have you tried the time profile instrument?

Comment: No and no. The problem is something you're doing in that transition. You might, for example, be trying to network synchronously, or you might have a threading problem. Use Instruments to find out. Don't guess: analyze.

Comment: Ohh I am using FireBase in my app and when the user clicks on the `SignInButton` I call the `AuthUser` method which goes to the Firebase server and auth's the user. Then in the callback function to this `AuthUser` method I do `if (!err) performSegueWithIdentifier(...)`. Could this request to the Firebase Server be creating this lag before I segue? But I am pretty sure this AuthUser method runs in a background thread.

Comment: Yes, it is running in the background, but if you don't performed the segue until it completes then you will get a delay as the segue won't be initiated until the authentication request returns. The delay is unavoidable but you can provide a better user experience by showing a UIactivityView or similar so that there is user feedback

Comment: Oh yes I already have that in. The problem is when it it segueing there is a lag and also when the `TableView` on the next ViewController is being presented some view objects of the previous Controller  (`SignInViewController`) are still present underneath `TableView` that is presented and then after like 0.5 seconds those view objects disappear from the previous `SignInViewController`. Not too sure how to fix this problem. Do you have any ideas on how to delay the segue for some time or somehow make it smoother.